# LLVM IR getelementptr invalid indices

Tags: llvm, llvm-ir

I'm currently in the phase of learning how to use LLVM. I'm trying to compile the following file via `llc struct-method.ll -o struct-method`.

**struct-method.ll**

```
; ModuleID = 'struct-method.ll'

@.formatstring = private unnamed_addr constant [13 x i8] c"%c\0A%ld\0A%lld\0A\00"

%box = type { i8, i32, i64 }

declare i32 @printf(i8* noalias nocapture, ...)

define i32 @set_prop_32(%box* %object, i32 %value) {
entry:
  %0 = getelementptr inbounds %box, %box* %object, i64 0, i64 1
  %1 = load i32, i32* %0
  ret i32 %1
}

define i32 @main() {
alloca:
  %mybox = alloca %box
  br label %entry

entry:
  %format = getelementptr [13 x i8], [13 x i8]* @.formatstring, i64 0, i64 0
  %0 = getelementptr inbounds %box, %box* %mybox, i64 0, i64 0
  %1 = getelementptr inbounds %box, %box* %mybox, i64 0, i64 1
  %2 = getelementptr inbounds %box, %box* %mybox, i64 0, i64 2

  store i8  65,       i8*  %0
  store i32 200,      i32* %1
  store i64 9999999,  i64* %2

  %f8 = load i8, i8* %0
  %f32 = load i32, i32* %1
  %f64 = load i64, i64* %2

  call i32 (i8*, ...) @printf(i8* %format, i8 %f8, i32 %f32, i64 %f64)

  call i32 (%box*, i32) @set_prop_32(%box* %mybox, i32 300)

  call i32 (i8*, ...) @printf(i8* %format, i8 %f8, i32 %f32, i64 %f64)

  ret i32 0
}
```

However I'm getting `invalid getelementptr indices` on line 11.

Does someone know why this could be and what I would write to solve this problem?

Edit:
I'm on macOS Sierra 10.12 on a Macbook Pro late 2013.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

as per http://llvm.org/docs/LangRef.html#getelementptr-instruction

"The type of each index argument depends on the type it is indexing into. When indexing into a (optionally packed) structure, only i32 integer constants are allowed (when using a vector of indices they must all be the same i32 integer constant). When indexing into an array, pointer or vector, integers of any width are allowed, and they are not required to be constant. These integers are treated as signed values where relevant"

in your case type { i8, i32, i64 } is struct type so try using i32 type indices.

instead of

```
%0 = getelementptr inbounds %box, %box* %object, i64 0, i64 1
```

try

```
%0 = getelementptr inbounds %box, %box* %object, i32 0, i32 1
```

Comment: Thanks! That worked. But why did it work in the first 4 instructions inside the entry block? BTW: Here is the finished version of what I was trying to achieve: https://github.com/KCreate/llvm-learning/blob/252f78b4634b69389b7d82fc89aa9a4a404bd646/struct-method.ll

Comment: For example this file compiles just fine: https://github.com/KCreate/llvm-learning/blob/dff4b4624e38553056a6875f7646fd30d318c6ae/struct.ll

Comment: first operand of gep is not struct but rather struct ptr, so first index is not indexing struct element but struct itself, so it is allowed to have any type of integer index as first index.(or if it contains ptr then for it also) so first index will get you (&box[i64 0 index]) value. see http://llvm.org/docs/GetElementPtr.html#why-is-the-extra-0-index-required for more info